# Oracle: Move old data to another table and compress it

Tags: database, oracle, compression

I have a table named ST and it has 30 columns. One of the column is named AS_OF_DATE and is in Date format. One of the values f.e. is '31.01.15'.

I want to make this table "lighter" (move  old/unneeded records) because it has 300 millions of records and is slowing down our processing.

So, I want to create another table named HISTORY and move all the records from ST with AS_OF_DATE<31.12.2015 to table HISTORY. Afterwards I want to compress table HISTORY, but I still want data to be readable (select only).

What's the best practice to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why do you want to compress *after* pushing data to the history table ? Usually, you would first create a compressed table, then push data into it.

Comment: If compressing a new history table and then moving the data there would do the trick, then I am also fine by that. I just want save some storage that's why I had compression on my mind.